# Use relational or object database as simple table without merging

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

My data can be presented in a relational database or an object database fashion. It is pretty small (500 Mb) in that format, but when I merge my tables to make it possible for scikit-learn to process it, (making it "tidy" as said in the statistics community), which is basically merging all the tables to make a unique table, it becomes way too big (17 Gb +) and it seems a waste of memory! This is because there is millions of rows that share a lot of attributes that are equal because they are related to the same object, so that makes of lot of data redundant, copied and repeated for nothing. I could use techniques to handle big data, that may be a solution, but isn't it possible to avoid it altogether ? Can I use my data directly in scikit-learn without having to merge explicitly the tables? Can I make an implicit merging that emulates the datastructure without taking additional memory?